# Is it possible to simulate an egg?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

Is it possible to simulate an egg?

Specifically, I was wondering how to handle simulating the yolk.

I was thinking fluid simulation, but it seems you can't a specify different viscosity for different parts of the fluid. (I'm not even sure if that would even be the way to go about it)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I also want to make an egg with the white and yolk in it and use it in some physics simulation, which might involve some interaction with it as well. Given that it's been about 5 years since the question has been posted (and also the answer), I wonder if the advancements in Blender would allow one to make an egg in a better way?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, you could use multiple fluid domains with different viscosity settings. The trick is to bake into different folders.

[image]

The UI allows you only to have one fluid domain therefore you need to disable the first one after baking in one folder by setting its type to none. After that you bake the second one and re-enable the first domain.

NOTE: that the domains shouldn't overlap while baking (I'm not sure about that), I tried to reproduce the steps descibed [here](http://users.xplornet.com/~gimble/blender/tutorials/fluid/multi_domain/fluid_multi_domain.htm)

The yolks volume was subtracted from the egg-white using a boolean modifier.

The result needs obviously some tweaking:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's been a while since you have done this. I wonder, are there better ways of simulating this now? Like more realistic simulations?