# How to have different fluid simulations going at the same time?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So I want to have about two or three different TYPES of fluid simulations in the one animation. So i want water falling off an edge as well as water shooting up into the sky and some water running through a pipe. Is this possible to do in the one animation?

Comment: If they don't interact with each other, it's as simple as adding different domains and baking to different directories. If they interact, it gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: So how exactly do i do that? how bake each of them separately? I tried doing it once but i couldn't get the other bake back?

Comment: If the two fluids need to interact with each other, they need to be in the same domain. And thus, the bake time increases.

Comment: Blender cannot have 2 interacting fluids in 1 domain, only multiple sources of 1 kind of fluid. That's a huge difference and a big constraint.

Comment: Well... you can have 2 inflow objects. That's what I thought he was talking about.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5822/599

Comment: Yeah I don't understand how to do it. I need a more in depth description.