# Is it possible to make fluid stick to vertical surfaces without using control object?

Tags: fluid-simulation

Looks like Noslip setting doesn't affect it that much. I'd really like the fluid to stop at the place where it touches the surface, while the upper rest of it would flow further till it contacts the surface and so on.

Also, I'd like to know how to make fluid to avoid *collect/assemble/gather/flock/congregate* in one place.

Comment: could you elaborate? what is the result you're getting? do you want your liquid in general to be sticky, or should it still be like water but become sticky when it hits a surface?

Comment: I don't understand that last sentence. What do you mean by "flock in one place"?

Comment: @Jbergman edited question ;)

Comment: Thanks for the synonyms, but they do not help me understand the question. The fluid will follow the direction of the gravity unless affected by obstacles or control objects. A picture or a blend file would help.

Comment: @Jbergman Sorry for waiting and those synonyms, I just don't really know what word better depicts what I want to get (not my native lang). Here's my [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kyulh44ggg1j5vr/Sticky_fluid.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the Daredevil intro credits? If so, you should have told us from the start (sure, I get that this is not the place to ask for tutorials, but it would have made things clearer). I actually did some experiments some time ago to do the same thing. Your basic setup is correct, even though there are plenty of details in your fluid sim that are off.

Comment: @Jbergman you got me detective! =) I am really trying to repeat it

Comment: Ok, so when you say that you don't want the fluid to collect in one place, do you mean that you want the fluid to be kind of layered? I mean to have one layer of fluid flow over another. English is not my native language either, so I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: @Jbergman well, kind of. I want the fluid to be ultimately slippy to itself and sticky to obstacle

Comment: Yeah, this is tricky. I've had some fun playing around with this, and a lot of settings have to be right for it to even remotely work. Anyway, you should look into the use of multiple domains (how to do that is covered elsewhere on this site) where the result of one fluid sim becomes an obstacle for the next one. I got some interesting results that way. There is no simple solution for your problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @Jbergman Could you show me those results of yours, please? It also would be nice if you had a link to that question you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: For the basics of setting up multiple fluid domains check http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5822/how-to-bake-multiple-fluid-simulations-in-one-scene This does not, however, address the question of "fake" interaction. There used to be good tutorial on the subject by Blender Tuts on youtube, but now that I searched, the account was closed due to alleged copyright infringement... I will play around some more and then I'll get back to you about my results.