# Does FLIP fluid support more then one domain in one scene?

Tags: physics

I would like to be able to repeat the animation many times in one scene. Fluid and gas solutions [How to bake multiple fluid simulations in one scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5822/how-to-bake-multiple-fluid-simulations-in-one-scene) don't seem to work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FLIP Fluids addon does not support more than one domain in a .blend file at the moment. A workaround to have multiple simulation animations in a scene is to export the simulation to the Alembic format through **File > Export > Alembic (.abc)**. Once exported, you can import the animated Alembic files back into your scene.

More information can be found in this documentation topic: https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Alembic-Export-Support

Comment: Oh, man, this had me pounding my head against the wall. One per scene, okay, maybe. One per file ... sux.