# 2 Different Fluid Simulation Domians in one scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, fluid-simulation

How do I get 2 different domains in the same scene? I am doing this because I want to reduce bake time is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5822/how-to-bake-multiple-fluid-simulations-in-one-scene

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5328/is-it-possible-to-simulate-an-egg/5330#5330

Comment: @cegaton Isn't this a duplicate then? The question is answered by any of the answer in the links.

Comment: @Leander not necessarily.